# Vue Props passed to SFC end up as attributes in DIV element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-component

I trying to pass an object to a child component. The object is from a fetch request to Strapi. I'm using Nuxt Bridge and Vue 2.6.14

The fetch in the parent

```
<script>
export default {

    async fetch() {
        this.featured = await fetch(
            'http://localhost:1337/api/getFeature',
        ).then((res) => res.json());

        this.feed = await fetch(
            'http://localhost:1337/api/getFeed'
        ).then((res) => res.json());
             
    },
    data(){
        return {
            featured: {},
            feed: []
                     }
        
    },

}
</script>
```

The component

```
<Feature v-bind="featured"/>
```

In the child component

```
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        featured:Object,
    }
}
</script>
```

The problem is that the object ends up as attributes on the first div tag in the child component.

```
<div title="Apple pie apple pie tootsie roll liquorice tiramisu topping" lede="Gummies lemon drops tootsie roll cake jelly beans candy cotton candy. Apple pie chocolate bar bear claw icing candy chocolate bar jelly pie" url="https://ik.imagekit.io/nnydigital/strapi/bryam_blanco_n_XKW_Ln8y9q_E_unsplash_44c4203534_M_Kx22_N6x_YD_abf84d3bbd_Mo5JvpCD3.jpg" created="Wed Jun 29 2022 10:38:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)" updated="Wed Jun 29 2022 10:38:08 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)" published="Wed Jun 29 2022 10:38:08 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)">
```

If use `<Feature :title="featured.title" />`

It works as expected. What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `v-bind` will spread the object properties.

So the child component `props` will not contain the `featured` object, but it will contain all its properties and it will bind it to the main element of the component, and the `props` will be like that.

```
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        title: string,
        lede: string,
        url: string,
        created: string,
        updated: string,
        published: string,
    }
}
</script>
```

If you want to send `featured` object itself, then you need to go with

```
<Feature :featured="featured"/>
```

Then you can get it from props like that

```
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        featured:Object,
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The docs on vuejs.org ( https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-passing-details), do not mention the spread or binding to main element

Comment: You are welcome, you can have a look at this section. https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#binding-multiple-properties-using-an-object

Answer (score -1):

According to your `<Featured/>` component there is only a `featured` prop.

to be able to pass `title` and others you need to add them in the props section of the component like this

```
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        published: string,
        title: string,
        lede: string,
        url: string,
        updated: string,
        created: string,
    }
}
</script>
```

else you will just pass the whole object at once and use it like this `this.props.title`